# Disable JUnit concurrent tests - BeforeClass, AfterClass issue

Tags: java, junit

I got two test classes: A and B.
The main problem is that JUnit enters in @BeforeClass of B before executing the @AfterClass of A.

Usually it is not a big deal but now I have to work on a shared database and this way it fails.

Sample:

```
public class A {
 @AfterClass
 public static void clearDb(){
  try{
  ...
  EntityManager em = ..
  em.getTransaction().begin();
  em.createQuery("DELETE FROM ClassName").executeUpdate();
  em.getTransaction().commit();
  }catch(...){...}
 }
 @Test
 public test(){
 ...
 }
}

public class B {
 @BeforeClass
 public static void clearDb(){
  try{
  ...
  EntityManager em = ..
  em.getTransaction().begin();
  em.clear();
  em.persist(...)
  em.getTransaction().commit();
  }catch(...){...}
 }
 @Test
 public test(){
 ...
 }
}
```

Connection: jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1

My question is: Is there a way to force JUnit to process as a single thread, or wait till the other class really cleaned up its stuff.

Comment: One way would probably be to have an external flag which the `@AfterClass` method changes after it has done everything needed and the `@BeforeClass` method should wait until that flag is set.

Comment: The parallelization is based on how you are running your tests. Are you using Maven (Surefire) or something else?

Comment: I think by default JUnit runs tests in a single thread.  What Runner are you using?

Comment: I am using the simple JUnit in a maven project. If I run it with maven test it is ok but the checker is running it as JUnit tests...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Old problem but if someone needs it:

As I got informed from many places there is no way to guarantee the Later.@BeforeClass and Earlier.@AfterClass methods order. The final solution was that I used different H2 databases.

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked into using the JUnit [Rule](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/wiki/Rules#externalresource-rules) annotation?

You can create an abstract class handles database state

```
import org.junit.Rule;
import org.junit.rules.ExternalResource;

public abstract class AbstractTest {

    public Object dbConnection;

    @Rule
    public ExternalResource resource = new ExternalResource() {
        @Override
        protected void before() {
            System.out.println("Setting up resource");
            // set up dbConnection
        }
        @Override
        protected void after() {
            System.out.println("Cleaning up resource");
            // clean db dbConnection
        }
   };

   public Object getDbConnection() {
        return dbConnection;
   }
 }
```

Then your tests would extend your abstract class

```
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;

public class SampleTest extends AbstractTest {

    @Test
    public void firstTest() {

        Object connection = getDbConnection();
        // interact with db using the provided connection
        System.out.println("do work 1");
    }

    @Test
    public void secondTest() {

        Object connection = getDbConnection();
        System.out.println("do work 2");
    }
}
```

Comment: I will look after this solution but I guess you misunderstood my question. The problem is that I have to different classes of tests and not two different functions aka @ Tests. As I see you made a a solution to an another problem. The main problem is that the multi-thread running runs the @ BeforeClass of the second test before the @ AfterClass of the first could have been ended.